# What’s the verb for discontinuing a call on a mobile phone?

Tags: word-choice, slang, technology

What is the correct term for stopping a conversation on a mobile phone?

In the old days we used to *put the phone down* when we were done talking. Do we now *put the mobile down* instead of putting the phone down, or do now we *turn it off* or *switch it off* even though the mobile phone is still working after the call is over?

Comment: To simply end the call since you can no longer hang up.

Comment: Where I speak English, we still use *hang up* with cellular phones, which usually just means pressing a (red) (hang up) button on the screen.

Comment: Hang up the phone. Ditch the cell. Nobody in America calls it a mobile, you need to understand.

Comment: We sometimes simply say, "cut the call".

Comment: @misensalem There's nothing wrong with "hang up", even though no physical hanging occurs. Likewise, there's nothing wrong with dialing a number, even though phones no longer have dials.

Comment: @tchrist He needs to understand what exactly? Who cares what you call your damn phone, the question isn't about that.

Comment: @tchrist Some people in America do call it a mobile, I know because they wrongly pronounce it as "mo-bul" and not "mo-bile" :)

Comment: @Hugo Ah yes, lovely Mobile, Alabama, which is "MO-beel". :)  They’re non-rhotic there, so it’s like they’re asking for "more beale", whatever that is. More peel? More beagle? Inquiring minds want to know. :)  I do know that if you tried to tell them they were saying it wrong, they’d soon enough be fixin’ to string ya up like a trussed yankee — ironically, in your case. :)

Comment: @JoeDark In point of fact, I actually call my pet peripatetic CDMA apparatus *Kermit*, which is something I do for a complex set of reasons related to his electric emerald coloration and his propensity for croaking at the least opportune moments—amongst other things. Now, I’m perfectly willing to grant you that the OP doesn’t care about Kermit, which is why I didn’t even bring it up. However, I completely fail to understand your disproportionate level of hostility about the matter. Is it perhaps that calling Kermit a mere *“cell”* somehow offends you? I know it certainly bothers ***him! :)***

Answer (score 3):

So odd... In the old days, the wall phone was the only phone in the house. Since the receiver hung on a bracket, everyone "hung-up". (The same with public pay-phones.)  Despite the changes in design, "hang-up" persevered. Now, while *you* can *end the call*, *disconnect*, *turn it off*, or whatever, If someone does it to *you*, (in the US) you will most likely say, "That $*#@! *hung-up* on me!"

(Although, when the rude person calls you back, he will say that he "lost you" in a "dead zone")

Answer (score 1):

*End, close a call or hang up* are used referring to a cell phone:

How to end a  [cell phone call](http://m.wikihow.com/Use-a-Cell-Phone) : (from Wiktionary)

> - End the call by pushing "end" (often indicated with red lettering or symbols). Calls will usually end automatically after the person you spoke to hangs up, but it's best to get into the habit of hanging up, especially since calls are billed by the minute.

Comment: Interesting. In what particular region or circumstance does one customarily say “close a call”? I’m not familiar with that usage; it sounds more like something you would say about closing the open help-ticket chain associated with an incoming call at some customer service center. So for example “I think we can close out that call now” might be said by the help-staff once the customer’s trouble were finally settled to their satisfaction; it would mean marking the matter as dealt with in some presumed online problem-tracking system they use internally.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misguided in that it asks for a prescriptive response. The best we can really do is to say how people actually do express that particular event, which will likely vary widely on a regional and even local basis. Even in the old days, I always heard of people in the UK "ringing off," while in the US we "hung up."

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, 'signed out', 'disconnected the call', 'hung up'. The last-mentioned would, I suppose, be universally understood.